# How to change the application view in the lastest ember version?

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to use the `Ember.Router` implemented in the latest version of ember (latest git master). It seems that `Ember.Application` is now able to instantiate the global application view layout and the router connects the outlets. What if the application has different section that don't share the same layout. 
For example, the ApplicationView of /library and /workspace are different and I need to change the layout when I go from the state 'library' to the state 'workspace'.
My current solution is to create and append my layout when I enter into one of these state and remove them on exit. Is there another way that is more compilant with the use of ApplicationView ?
Or, is it possible to have a sub outlet ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have inner outlets, so when entering a parent state, you could bind an application view being the layout, and having sub-outlets (named as needed), which content will be set by children states.

Comment: Do you have a more specific example ? From now, I have an ApplicationView that have two outlets {{outlet toolbar}} and {{outlet application}}. When I go to state library I need to change application into LibraryView which is straightforward. But the library view has also outlets : {{outlet list}} and {{outlet detail}}. Where should I set up these inner outlets ?

Comment: I am currently working on a fiddle illustrating this. I have to complete it & I will update this answer.

Comment: Here is a post that talks about the use of outlet http://stackoverflow.com/a/10804575/1259390 But What if the outlet contentView is itself composed of outlets ?

Comment: In fact, you now have access to a WIP future official guide here: https://emberjs-staging-new.herokuapp.com/guides/outlets

It's pretty clear and contains illustration for inner-outlets.

Comment: thank you. I finaly got what I need as illustrated by this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jrabary/BRAgP/ And in fact, this guide is awesome.

Comment: @jrabary, Your fiddle doesn't work now, can you please update it?